# Flow of my spark streaming program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Small question about the flow of my spark streaming program.

I have this function :

```
def parse(msg: String): Seq[String]
```

Which actually split a "good" message into multiple strings, and, if the string is "bad", returns an empty Seq.

I'm reading the messages from a kafka topic, and I want to send the results of the parsing into two different topics:
If the message is "good", send the result of the parsing to the topic "good_msg_topic"
If the message is "bad", send the "bad" message to the topic "bad_msg_topic"

To achieve that, I did this :

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val res = rdd.map(msg => msg.value() -> parse(msg.value()))

  res.foreach(pair => {
    if (pair._2.isEmpty) {
      producer.send(junkTopic, pair._1)
    } else {
      pair._2.foreach(m => producer.send(splitTopic, m))
    }
  })
})
```

However, I feel like this is not optimal. Using a Map Object to associate the original message to the result may slow down the process...

I'm beginning with Spark and Scala, so I think one could do better.

Any idea on how I could improve that ? Changing the signature of the parse function if also possible if you think it's better.

Thank you

Comment: *Using a Map Object to associate the original message to the result may slow down the process*. What exactly are you worried about? Have you measured the performance and found this a bottleneck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be too concerned regarding performance if you haven't already measured this and found a bottleneck.

One thing I can think of which might make this code clearer is to use an ADT to describe the result type:

```
sealed trait Result
case class GoodResult(seq: Seq[String]) extends Result
case class BadResult(original: String) extends Result
```

Have `parse` return `Result`

```
def parse(s: String): Result
```

And then use `map` on `DStream` instead of `RDD`:

```
stream
.map(msg => parse(msg.value())
.foreachRDD { rdd => 
   rdd.foreach { result => 
     result match {
       case GoodResult(seq) => seq.foreach(value => producer.send(splitTopic, value))
       case BadResult(original) => producer.send(junkTopic, original)
     }
   }
}
```